Android Auto activate tab content
I'm currently working on integrating the Tab template in Android Auto using the react-native-carplay library. I'm facing an issue with activating the tab content programmatically. Can anyone provide guidance on how to accomplish this?
Here is the code:
const gridItemImage = require('../assets/images/go.png');

const gridTemp = new GridTemplate({
    buttons: [
        {
            id: 'Odo',
            titleVariants: ['Odo'],
            image: gridItemImage,
        },
    ],
})
const paneTemplate = new PaneTemplate({
    id: 't1',
    title: 'Tab',
    pane: {
        image: {
            uri: `${Image.resolveAssetSource(
                require('../assets/images/map.jpg'),
            ).uri
                }`,
        },
        items: [
            {
                id: 'p1',
                text: 'Samplew',
                detailText: 'Disconnected',
            },
            {
                id: 'p2',
                text: 'Odometer',
                detailText: '0 km',
            },
            {
                id: 'p3',
                text: 'No Alerts',
            },
        ],
    },
});

const tabBarTemplateConfig = {
    headerAction: { type: 'appIcon' },
    id: 'tabBar',
    templates: [
        {
            title: 'Trailer',
            id: 't1',
            icon: {
                uri: `${Image.resolveAssetSource(
                    require('../assets/images/caravan.png'),
                ).uri
                    }`,
            },
            template: paneTemplate
        },
        {
            title: 'Service',
            id: 't2',
            color: 'red',
            icon: {
                uri: `${Image.resolveAssetSource(
                    require('../assets/images/alert-warning.png'),
                ).uri
                    }`,
            },
            template: gridTemp,
        },
    ],
    onTemplateSelect: (template, event) => {
        console.log('template is clicked: ', template.id);
        console.log('template: ', template);

    },
};

export const tabBarTemplate = new TabBarTemplate(tabBarTemplateConfig);

I want to active the second tab content. Does anybody know how to set active tab content. Many thank to you
